# Record Count always -1 when using ADO in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Ive an excel sheet with more than 100 rows. So I tried to read those using ADO as follows.

```
Dim db As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set db = New Connection
Dim extProperties As String
Dim ConnectStr As String, sql As String


extProperties = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;ReadOnly=False;"
ConnectStr = printf("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties=""{1}""", fn, extProperties)


db.Open ConnectStr
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Resource_Data$A1:A20]"


Set rs = New Recordset
rs.Open sql, db
```

MsgBox rs.RecordCount

But always the record count is -1

Resource_Data is a sheet in my workbook. **fn** is a filename passed to this function

Comment: If you want to use `.RecordCount`, you have to first issue a `.MoveLast`

Comment: But now it says Rowset does not support fetching backword when I added rs.movelast before the messagebox

Comment: Look at the optional arguments you are not specifying when you open the recordset.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `CursorType` in the Open method.

By default the `CursorType` is `adOpenForwardOnly`, which will result in a recordset that doesn't return the record count.

Try `adOpenKeyset` or `adOpenStatic`.